Greedy algoithm exchange proof for array symmetry swap to reduce same neighbour elements
Given an array of integers of size n, the task is to reduce the disturbance of the array where disturbance is counted as number of same neighbouring pairs.
Ex:

2 1 2 2 1 1

The disturbance is 2. As two pair of neighbouring (2,2) and (1,1).
The task is to reduce disturbance and the only operation which can be carried out is to use symmetric swap. Swap i'th and (n-i) th element.
The algorithm to do that is to start from the middle and

IF a[i]==a[i-1] or a[n-i]==a[n-i+1] then swap the element.

How can we prove that this greedy algorithm works using greedy exchange argument or any other ?
Problem Source : https://codeforces.com/contest/2033/problem/C

What are the possible changes to the number of "disturbances" of a single symmetrical swap?

As in per proposed algorithm, either it stays the same or decreases. Looking for proof that the resultant will be the optimal one.

What are the possible changes to the number of "disturbances" when you symmetrically swap (reverse) a[i+1] to a[n-i]?

It would be same as only swapping a[i+1] and a[n-i] as nothing changes inside that subarray.

Make a sketch - assuming i+2<n, the former a[i+1] and a[i+2] are still neighbours after reversal.

Thank you. OK, I get this, from this how to make the exchange argument ?

Let $c(A)$ be the disturbance of an array $A$, and Let $df(A,B)$ be the smallest index $i$ greater than $\frac{n}{2}$, such that $A[i]\neq B[i]$, or $df(A,B) = \infty$ if no such index exists.
Here is a formal proof.
Let $O$ be an optimal array, and $A$ the array resulting by applying your algorithm. Assume that $O$ is not equal to the solution given by your algorithm. Let $i = df(A, O)$. It holds at $i$ that either your condition is met, and hence, your algorithm made a swap and the optimal didn't, or the condition is not met, but the optimal made the swap.
Let $O'$ be the array resulting from $O$ by applying a swap on all elements from the $i$th element to the last element.
Claim 1. $c(O') \leq c(O)$.
Proof.
Let $r = \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$. It holds that

$O'[1:n-i+1] = O[n:i]$,
$O'[n-i+2:r-1] = O[n-i+2:r-1]$,
$O'[r:i-1] = O[r:i-1]$,
and $O'[i:n] = O[n-i+1:1]$.

Hence, $O'$ results from $O$ by partitioning it into four segments and reordering (and reversing) four of them. We lose exactly the adjacencies $O[i-1, i]$ and $O[n-i+1, n-i+2]$ and get the new adjacencies $O[i,n-i+2]$ and $O[n-i+2, i+1]$.
It holds that $O[i] = O[i-1]$ or $O[n-i+1] = O[n-i+2]$. Let us assume that $O[i] = O[i-1]$ since the other case is symmetric. if $O[i] = O[n-i+2]$ and $O[i-1] = O[n-i+1]$, then it holds that $O[n-i+1] = O[n-i+2]$ and hence, $c(O')=c(O)$. In all other cases, the disturbance is decreased at least by one (due to the original equality) and increased by at most one (due to the new adjacencies). Hence it holds in all cases that $c(O')\leq c(O)$.

Claim 2. $df(O',A) > df(O,A)$.
Proof. This holds since $O'[r:i-1] = O[r:i-1] = A[r:i-1]$ (by the definition of $i$ and $O'[i] = A[i]$ since both differ from $O[i]$.

Finally, since $df$ strictly increases after each step, it holds clearly that after at most $r$ iterations we reach an array $X$ with $df(X,A) = \infty$, i.e.\ $X=A$, and $c(X)= c(O)$.
